# Where to write Success and Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Here I'm using Angularjs1.x and here is my condition. If condition is success then show the table otherwise throw an error. I know some code if its Success.

**AngCtrl.Js**

```
 $scope.BtnCall = function () {

  ServiceCntrl.CallData().then(function (d) {
        $scope.EmpData = d.data;

    });

 }
```

**AngService.Js**

```
eApp.service("ServiceCntrl", function ($http) {
var xx = '';

xx= $http({
        data: formData,
        method: 'post',
        url: Url,
        datatype: "json"
    }).success(function (rsp) {
        RspData = rsp;
        return RspData;
    }).error(function (rsp) {
        console.log('Error');
    });
    return xx;
};
```

Comment: Where is `CallData()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x.then` receives two functions `x.then(function(){}, function(){});` first function is called when promise is successfully resolved and second function is called if promise is rejected(failed).

If your service function is return $http promise then your first function can have a parameter named(anything you like) and it will have response data that you can use. Second function can receive error parameters if any.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at angular [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation.

If your service is returning the promise of the get request, then you can write

```
$scope.BtnCall = function () {
    var x = ServiceCntrl.CallData();
    x.then(function(response) {
   //Success callback
   //code on success goes here
   //response.data

  }, function(response) {
    //error callback
    //code on error goes here
    // server returns response with an error status.

  });
```

you can use the [ng-show/ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to show and hide the contents on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your success/fail code as the following:

```
$scope.BtnCall = function() {
   var x = ServiceCntrl.CallData();
   x.then(function(result) {
       // Success code here 
       // Do something and resolved the promise           
   }, function(reason) {
       // Error code here
       // You may handle/reject the reason in params
   });
});
```

*See also the [Angular docs for `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).*

Answer (score -1):

**The AngularJS $http service makes a request to the server, and returns a response**
        The example above executes the $http service with an object as an argument. The object is specifying the HTTP method, the url, what to do on success, and what to do on failure.

```
 $scope.BtnCall = function () {
      ServiceCntrl.CallData().then(function (d) {
            $scope.EmpData = d.data;
        });
     }
```

**AngService.Js :**

```
  eApp.service("ServiceCntrl", function ($http) { 
    var xx = '';
    xx= $http({ 
             data: formData,
             method: 'post',
             url: Url, 
             datatype: "json" 
           }).success(function (rsp) {
              RspData = rsp; 
              return RspData; 
          }).error(function (rsp) { 
            console.log('Error');
           });
         return xx; 
    };
```